# R Shiny How make a help box appear with an action button

Tags: r, button, shiny

I have created an action button as follows in my ui

```
div(style="display:inline-block",actionButton("action", label = "Help"))
```

I want this button to create a help box which the user can close which contains text on how to use this app. How do i do this?

Also, how do I customise this button? such as font, colour, alignment...

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Clicking the action button increments a value, initially 0.  You could use `renderUI` in your `server.R` file to define a widget that is empty when input$action is even, and `helpText` when it is odd.  That way, the same action button would both open and close the help.

```
output$HelpBox = renderUI({
  if (input$action %% 2){
    helpText("Here is some help for you")
  } else {
    return()
  }
})
```

In `ui.R`, use the `uiOutput` function to display the widget.  Remember that it will display nothing until the action button is clicked.

```
uiOutput("HelpBox")
```